# Are Tomcat server and Tomcat linked with Eclipse different?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed `Tomcat 7 server` on Windows on port `8088`.

Now I have added the server in Eclipse.

But I am not sure whether I need to keep the Tomcat running by going in the Tomcat directory or I have to close that and run from Eclipse?
And how will Eclipse know that I have setup the Tomcat on port 8088?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do i need to keep the tomcat running
>   by going in the tomcat directory or i
>   have to close that and run from
>   eclispe.

No you don't need to keep tomcat running outside. You can run/stop it whenever you want from eclipse.

> how will eclipse know that i have
>   setup the 8088 port

You will find project named `Server` or `Servers`; depends on eclipse version; in your workspace; in which you have added tomcat. It has tomcat configuration file which tells eclipse how to manage tomcat. It has a file called `server.xml` which contain port information that is on which port tomcat will run.

Comment: the server.xml has port 8090 listed but the eclispe says that can not start server because port 8009 is used somewhere. where has this port come from

Comment: @Name: Do you have any other tomcat instance running concurrently. Because beside connection port `tomcat` needs some others ports to work like redirect port. So may be you also need change that cause two instance can not access same port at same time.

Comment: the other instance is running outside eclispe not inside. you said many instances can run

Comment: @Name: yes many instance can run on one machine. But they all need different ports to run on. It does not matter from where you start tomcat inside or outside of eclipse but their ports must be different from each other all port conflict will occur that is what you are facing now.

Comment: @Name: Either in inside/outside tomcat's `server.xml` change port in this line. ` <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />`

Answer (score 2):

In the server view, you can double-click on your tomcat server and change the ports. This means that the folder where you have tomcat running (CATALINA_HOME) can still be used run Tomcat "production" and eclipse will use the same binaries to run within WTP.  However, all other folders will be confiurable for your "dev" instance.

Actually you'd better change the settings to make sure there is no collision between eclipse ports and the ports declared at windows level.

Another simple solution is to stop tomcat at the windows level.  Eclipse will take care of its own instance.

Other useful settings you can modify are the timeouts (in debug it's sometimes necessary), the deploy folder and even add some more web apps (modules tab).

Comment: so it means outside eclipse i can run in IE localhost:8088 and in eclispe i can run localhost:8085  at same time

Comment: @Name: yes you can but it requires 2 different tomcat instances. With one instance you can not do this.

Comment: That's correct.  Eclipse does not affect your "prod" instance.  If you do not change the settings you will find a mini 'CATALINA_BASE' environment under myworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0  The tmp0 is for your first config, if you run a second instance it will be in tmp1 etc...  Finally, you will discover a new server type launch configuration generated for you.  In this launch config, you can add any jvm argument you want (such as JMX settings for instance).  basically you're in full control of your dev tomcat configuration.